# maven git-commit-id-plugin: commitId of subfolder/submodule

Tags: maven

I'm using the `maven-git-commit-id-plugin` maven plugin to get data like commitId. My maven project has some submodules in subfolders, like this:

```
hfe/pom.xml -
            - backend/pom.xml
            - frontend/pom.xml
```

`hfe` is the git-checkout, so there the folder .git exists.

In `hfe/pom.xml` in the build section I add the `maven-git-commit-id-plugin` so that it will be executed in every submodule.

If I do now a `mvn package` in the folder `hfe/backend/`, I will get the latest commitId of the whole project in the generated git-property-file. Is it possible to get the latest commitId of the subfolder hfe/backend.

To make it clear, I would like to have the commitId 90791bcf... in the file hfe/backend/target/git.properties, but in the moment I get the commitId d022a39342...:

```
/projects/hfe>git log -n 1 backend
commit 90791bcf145ee635c61f25c0ac62d0d66c49307f
Author: me
Date:   Fri May 10 12:30:31 2019 +0200

/projects/hfe>git log -n 1
commit d022a39342ecd6bcedeafbaf4bd80db495fdf23c (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: other
Date:   Sun May 12 21:58:50 2019 +0200
```

Maybe there is another maven plugin which can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this [`git-commit-id/maven-git-commit-id-plugin` issue 137](https://github.com/git-commit-id/maven-git-commit-id-plugin/issues/137#issuecomment-418144756) would help:

- running the plugin multiple times with different git projects without overwriting already generated properties.
- using the Git submodule SHA1 instead of the parent project

From [`TheSnoozer`](https://github.com/TheSnoozer):

```
<!-- GIT COMMIT ID PLUGIN CONFIGURATION -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <id>get-the-git-infos-for-repository-one</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                                <prefix>git1</prefix>
                <dotGitDirectory>pathToRepositoryOne/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/repository_one_git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <id>get-the-git-infos-for-repository-two</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                                <prefix>git2</prefix>
                <dotGitDirectory>pathToRepositoryTwo/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/repository_two_git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>false</verbose>
        <skipPoms>false</skipPoms>
        <injectAllReactorProjects>true</injectAllReactorProjects>
        <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you. Our problem is that in our case, git2 is just a subfolder of git1, so there's no separate .git directory; it's part of the same tree in git.

Comment: @user1717259 if g2 is a submodule of g1, that should still work. Try it out.

Comment: Yes the plugin does run if you provide <dotGitDirectory>pathToRepositoryTwo/.git</dotGitDirectory> even if the .git doesn't exist.

Unfortunately, the two properties files that get generated differ only in git.build.time.

What I was hoping for was the same difference I get with git log


$ git log master.. -n 1 -- /blah/git1/blah/git2/
Date: Thu Aug 22 11:20:48 2019 +0100

JIRA-61 Added a temp file to git2 


$ git log master.. -n 1 -- /blah/git1/
Date: Thu Aug 22 11:36:13 2019 +0100

JIRA-61 Added a temp file to git1

Answer (score 1):

A Git submodule's ".git" directory isn't located in its root. It is located inside the **enclosing** repository's `modules` directory.

Using your example:

```
hfe/
  - pom.xml
  - .git/          <- hfe's ".git" directory
    - modules/
      - backend/   <- the submodule's ".git" directory
  - backend/
    - pom.xml
    - .git         <- *not* a directory!
```

Since the value of the plugin's `<dotGitDirectory>` configuration property needs to change for the module project, you need to explicitly declare executions for both (instead of relying on Maven's build inheritance).

#### Configure two executions of the plugin in the top level pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <id>get-hfe-git-properties</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>revision</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <prefix>hfe</prefix>
        <dotGitDirectory>.git</dotGitDirectory>
        <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/hfe-git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <id>get-backend-git-properties</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>revision</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <prefix>backend</prefix>
        <dotGitDirectory>.git/modules/backend</dotGitDirectory>
         <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/backend-git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  <executions>
</plugin>
```

#### Configure one execution in each pom.xml

`hfe/pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <id>get-git-properties</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>revision</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  <executions>
  <configuration>
    <prefix>hfe</prefix>
    <dotGitDirectory>.git</dotGitDirectory>
      <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

`backend/pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <id>get-git-properties</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>revision</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  <executions>
  <configuration>
    <prefix>backend</prefix>
    <dotGitDirectory>../.git/modules/backend</dotGitDirectory>
    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Got it. I was wondering why my 2019 answer was downvoted. Your setup seems more precise. Upvoted.